# How to set "setCanvasUrlPath" dynamically?

Tags: canvas

Im new to Canvas SDK. Can anyone help me to  bind the CanvasPath dynamically?

Im invoking canvass app though VF page on contact page(Standard detail), in canvasURL i want to bind contactID as well.

is it doable with canvas? if so, can you please pitch in some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the url. You can send the contact Id as parameter. Your canvas app can then do changes on its side based on this id or can redirect the user to a new url that has this id.

[Apex:CanvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm) supports sending parameters. You can have your canvas do something like this

```
<apex:page controller="contactCanvas">
   <apex:canvasApp developerName="contactCanvas" parameters="{!contactId}" />
</apex:page>
```

On the other side you can write code to retrieve this parameter, which goes something like

```
var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
var contactId = sr.context.environment.parameters.contactId;
//You can do whatever customization with the Id you just have
```